# JavaScript ООП, передать Jquery объект через bind

Tags: javascript, jquery

В методе obr необходимо получить объект jquery, на котором сработало событие. Каким образом это можно сделать?

Пытаюсь прописать таким образом и, ожидаемо, получаю пустоту:

```
class MenuAnimation{
    constructor(){
        $('a').on('click', this.obr.bind(this, $(this)));
    }

    obr(elem, e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.alertMessage(elem.text());
    }

    alertMessage(txt){
        alert(txt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может так?

```
class MenuAnimation {
    constructor() {
        $('a').on('click', this.obr.bind(this));
    }

    obr(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let elem = $(e.target);
        this.alertMessage(elem.text());
    }

    alertMessage(txt) {
        alert(txt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Так obr же метод класса, а Вы вызывает как функцию. Ваш код вернет "obr is not defined". Да и this.obr я написать не могу, потому что для функции на событие клик this не является используемым классом.

Comment: @Andrey_A обновил ответ

Comment: `bind` забыл - он нужен.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну да, this же есть..

Comment: Благодарю Вас! Все работает.

Comment: @Andrey_A, тогда прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо :)